# Basement sliding glass window (Pella) - how to remove the pane opposite of the sash

Tags: windows

[image: Pella Basement Sliding Glass Window]

I just installed a Pella basement sliding glass window in my house. It went well, but I have a question. How do you remove the non-sash pane? I Googled this like crazy but the only things that come up are how to remove the *sash*, which is super easy but not what I need to know.

What if the non-sash pane breaks? I can't imagine that one would have to remove the entire window and replace it. At least I hope not.

Also, what is the non-sash window pane area/thing called?

Comment: I think the terms for a window like you have is to call the two parts the "slider" and "fixed" sections of the door,

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak for all sliding windows but on mine the fixed section has some bracket things in the center corners top and bottom that keep it in place and prevent it from being lifted up to clear the lower track.

Removal on most of these involves lifting to clear the track on the bottom and then swinging the bottom away from the frame. Many times the movable section has to be removed before the fixed section can be removed. On mine both sections have to be removed toward the inside.

Comment: Yet, on some units (not speaking of Pella specifically), the fixed sash is siliconed in place and would take effort to remove. Some of those same units have flanges (wrong word, but I hope you get the idea) clipped in around the glass, so replacement would only involve removing the flanges. If it breaks (which is rare), call a good glass place. They'll have seen it all before and can fix it.